# Telegram How To Detect When a group or channel change its name?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot, telethon

I am using Telegram API to extract some information in some chats and channels and I have made a list containing all groups' names such as:

StockNews
Englishchat
CorronaNews

I made a python loop on those groups to extract the data. But if EnglishChat has its name changed into EnglishChatOffical my script doesn't work because I have to update this group name in my list manually.

How could I detect such a change ?

Best

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just store the group chat_id?

Comment: the chat id doesn't change ?

Comment: Only if the group updates to a supergroup, and you get an event for that

Comment: The only way is to loop through the stored chat ids and call getChat method to obtain chat information and then compare it.

Comment: thanks a lot, I did it it works